# Get NGINX to serve .gz compressed asset files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, gzip, assets

Rails 3.1 has a convenient system which can compress files into .gz files. However, instead what I've done is I've moved all the asset files that are created with assets:precompile to a static webserver. This all works, but how can I get nginx to serve the .gz files normally?

Comment: Since Rails 4.2 `rake assets:precompile` no longer creates .gz files . Some fixes https://multiplethreads.wordpress.com/2015/08/08/generate-gzip-assets-with-rails-sprockets-3/

Answer (score 62, accepted):

1) ensure you have Nginx > 1.2.x (to proper headers modifications) and compile with **--with-http_gzip_static_module** option

2) Enable this option **gzip on** (to serve back-end response with gzip header)

3) Setup assets location with **gzip_static on**
(to serve **all.css.gz, all.js.gz** files directly)

4) Prevent of etag generation and last-modify calculation for assets

5) Turn on the right Cache-control to cache SSL served static assets,
unless they will be expired once browser is closed

```
  location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascripts|stylesheets|swfs|system)/ {
      gzip_static on;
      expires     max;
      add_header  Cache-Control public;
      add_header  Last-Modified "";
      add_header  ETag "";
  }
```

if you would like to get full Nginx configuration, you can see [this gist on Github](https://gist.github.com/3052776).

**open_file_cache** helps you to cache: open file descriptors, their sizes, modification times and directory lookups, which is helpful for high load on the file system.

**UPDATE:** If you are living on the edge, turn on the SPDY to boost the SSL connection.

Comment: don't forget to turn off any logs for assets:   access_log /dev/null;
  error_log /dev/null;

Comment: use **/dev/null**, because "off" is a file anyway

Comment: You only need to use /dev/null if you want to turn off the error log (which you really shouldn't anyway).  access_log accepts an 'off' argument which actually turns off logging, so the lines aren't even generated in the first place.

Comment: To minimize the load on file system, don't forget to mount a device with **noatime** option. It will prevent an update access time on each assets while access every time.

Comment: Depending on your situation, you might want to remove images from your gzip list. It doesn't help much and eats CPU. Better compress them before uploading to the server.

Comment: @Anatoly It's been a long time since you wrote this. Do we today need to turn off the headers `Last-Modified` and `ETag`? I am trying to figure out why that's necessary for serving pre-compressed files with `gzip_static on`.

Comment: Not really required anymore, such micro optimisations become less and less noticeable

Comment: @Anatoly Yes, gzip_static is indeed today a micro optimization. But, if someone needed `gzip_static on`, was removal of `Last-Modified` and `Etag` required to support it? (or, you had mentioned that for some other purpose?).